# How to remove rows in Google Sheets from an imported HTML table?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, html-imports

Working on a spreadsheet. I want to drop rows 98 through 102, as well as row 164 & 117.

But I cannot figure out how.

```
Formula in use: =(query(query(IMPORTHTML("https://www.tcgplayer.com/categories/trading-and-collectible-card-games/disney-lorcana/price-guides/the-first-chapter","table"),"select Col2,Col5,Col6,Col7"),"select * order by Col2 ASC",1))
```

Note: I don't know anything about formulas. You're going to have to spell it out for me.

Tried to "delete Row." It just loads back in.

I found several google search results for dropping or selecting specific columns, but google didn't help with results for dropping rows.

Also found a formula for removing duplicate rows. I don't have duplicates. I just have rows I want to eliminate.

Comment: `rows 98 through 102, as well as row 164 & 117` What is "special" about these rows that you want to drop them?

Comment: rows 98 through 102 have a "rarity" value (ColI) of "Null."
 row 164 & 117 have the word "oversized" (among others) in Column H
Both instances are irrelevant to the data I'm collecting.

Comment: Sorry to be a pedant, but I've just run the `IMPORTHTML` part of your formula and the issues that you mention are NOT shown in the raw data. You _can_ remove those named rows (and I'll do that) but for interest's sake would you cite a specific Product name so that we can compare data.

Comment: I'm sure I understand what you're asking?

I have 4 columns and 217 rows. Columns are labeled "Product Name," "Rarity," "Number," and "Market Price."

In the "Rarity" column, there are 5 cells with the word "None."

In the "Product name" column, there are 2 cells that contain "(oversized)"
These are "Mulan - Imperial Soldier (Oversized)" and "Hades - King of Olympus (Oversized)"

Comment: FWIW, I get 1 header plus 216 data rows.

Comment: That is accurate

Answer (score 0):

You are importing data from a website using `IMPORTHTML`. You want to "remove" given row numbers.

There are probably several ways to answer this question. Using `QUERY`, it is not a matter of deleting "rows" based on a row number but using the `WHERE` clause to exclude records based on data attributes.

There are two attributes to exclude:

- Rarity: "None"
- Name: contains "(Oversized)"
- `where not Col5 = 'None' and not Col2 contains '(Oversized)'`

The `NOT` qualifier will exclude these attributes.

- `NOT` appears before the relevant comparison clause
- `and` will exclude both of the attributes

---

```
=query(    
IMPORTHTML("https://www.tcgplayer.com/categories/trading-and-collectible-card-games/disney-lorcana/price-guides/the-first-chapter","table",1),
"select Col2, Col5, Col6, Col7 
where not Col5 = 'None' and not Col2 contains '(Oversized)'")
```

---